# Nested EditorFor/DisplayFor override field name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Short of overriding `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` with an empty string, is there a way to keep the prefix from coming through on a nested set of strongly-typed EditorFor or DisplayFor helper calls?

Here's the ugly markup/code I have working so far:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Web.Mvc.SelectList>" %>
<% ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = ""; %>
<%=Html.DropDownList("sort", Model)%>
```

I've tried the *For overload that allows specifying `htmlFieldName` but that only changes the immediate level. If I have a prefix at the point of that call, I just change what is appended to the prefix.

I could write the template markup by hand, but doing so for a `SelectList` object seems like I will just end up copying over the MVC source with a single tweak since it involves object data binding logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a property on your view model, rather than just doing dropdown list directly on the model, you can put a DataAnnontation attribute on it.

```
public class MyModel
{
   [Display(Name="Your Favorite Choices")]
   public string[] Choices {get; set;}
}
```

then in your code

```
<%= Html.LableFor(m => m.Choices) %><br />
<%=Html.DropDownList("sort", Model.Choices)%>
```

Should use that name.

[Hope I got it right from memory. :)]

Here's the MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.displayattribute.aspx

Comment: I'm looking for a way to override the prefix in the HTML field's ID attribute (used for model binding on the return trip), not its user-facing display name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, but, if you render the "child" views as partials instead of EditorFor then the fields will not be prefixed.